# T-SQL JSON_MODIFY Error: Argument data type uniqueidentifier (datetime, money etc) is invalid

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql

JSON_MODIFY does not support many base types in the 3rd argument. How fix it?

```sql
    DECLARE @info NVARCHAR(200)='{"name":"John","skills":["C#","SQL"]}'
    
    SELECT JSON_MODIFY(@info, '$.code', NEWID())
    
    SELECT JSON_MODIFY(@info, '$.date', GETDATE())
    
    SELECT JSON_MODIFY(@info, '$.cost', CAST(1 AS money))
```

> Msg 8116, Level 16, State 1, Line 3 
> Argument data type uniqueidentifier is invalid for argument 3 of
> json_modify function.

> Msg 8116, Level 16, State 1, Line 5 
> Argument data type datetime is invalid for argument 3 of json_modify
> function.

> Msg 8116, Level 16, State 1, Line 8 
> Argument data type money is invalid for argument 3 of json_modify
> function.

Comment: Is that a question or a statement? You're right, but that's not really T-SQL's fault. JSON itself has few types. It's actually a good idea to force you to specify what kind of string or numeric value you'd like in your JSON, as opposed to relying on the (often arcane) implicit conversion rules. JSON simply has no standard way of representing dates, for example. ISO 8601 is a popular choice, but even then not everyone agrees on details (how many positions are allowed for milliseconds? Is a `T` mandatory?)

Comment: perhaps you need to take a step back and "re-think" for a second if you like to store and manipulate graphs, then perhaps you should store data as a graph and not as Json, SQL server does allow Graph https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/sql-development/sql-server-graph-databases-part-1-introduction/

Answer (score 1):

Try use my  dbo.JSON_MODIFY function that solved problem

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.JSON_MODIFY(@expression nvarchar(max), @path nvarchar(max), @newValue sql_variant)
RETURNS nvarchar(max) 
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @tempJson nvarchar(max) = (SELECT @newValue AS col1 FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER)

    RETURN JSON_MODIFY(@expression, @path, JSON_VALUE(@tempJson, '$.col1'))
END
GO

DECLARE @info NVARCHAR(100)='{"name":"John","skills":["C#","SQL"]}'
PRINT dbo.JSON_MODIFY(@info, '$.code', NEWID())
PRINT dbo.JSON_MODIFY(@info, '$.date', GETDATE())
PRINT dbo.JSON_MODIFY(@info, '$.cost', CAST(1 AS money))
GO
```

Output results:

> {"name":"John","skills":["C#","SQL"],"code":"85543240-38C5-4647-B555-4388ADAD71F0"}
>   {"name":"John","skills":["C#","SQL"],"date":"2019-10-03T16:16:10.600"}
>   {"name":"John","skills":["C#","SQL"],"cost":"1.0000"}

Comment: This will represent all numeric values as strings. While that's not a bad idea from the perspective of preserving precision, it's probably not what's expected for exact values (e.g. `"id": 42`). Converting `FLOAT` values gives even worse results: you get T-SQL's confusing approach to formatting floating-point values in JSON *as a string*, e.g. `"1.000000000000000e+000"`. Use with great care.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a few reasons why updating JSON in SQL is a bad idea starting with the configuration options of those that consume the json. If you use need to be able to round-trip the JSON and you use something like NewtonSoft default settings you would need to cast/ format a date string in a particular way

```
select format(GetUtcDate(),'yyyy-MM-dd''T''HH:mm:ss.fff')+'Z'
```

in your sample, you should probably use if you use .net to read the data when it leaves your database... in any way you need to make sure you align your database with those that consume the data and, in my use-case use format to make sure the data does not generate corrupt JSON.

```
DECLARE @info NVARCHAR(100)='{"name":"John","skills":["C#","SQL"]}'
```

in your modify this would look like this

```
SELECT JSON_MODIFY(@info, '$.date', format(GetUtcDate(),'yyyy-MM-dd''T''HH:mm:ss.fff')+'Z')
```